# Subtraindo matrizes com argumentos diferentes

Tags: r, array, matriz

Nós podemos subtrair duas matrizes (ou dois vetores) que foram escritos com diferentes comandos?

Exemplo:

```
x<-array(1:4,c(4,1,1))
y<-cbind(c(1:4))
x-y
"Error> non-conformable objects"
```

Isso significa que ambos os vetores tem que utilizar os mesmos comandos?

Answer (score 1):

O seu objeto `x` tem dimensões 4x1x1 e o objeto y somente 4x1, você não pode subtrair objetos com dimensões diferentes.

Se você colocar as dimensões  4x1 em `x` funciona:

```
x<-array(1:4,c(4,1))
y<-cbind(c(1:4))
x-y
     [,1]
[1,]    0
[2,]    0
[3,]    0
[4,]    0
```

Answer (score 0):

não; significa apenas que `x` e `y`são objetos de dimensões diferentes. por exemplo,

```
      x<-array(1:4,dim=c(4))
      y = 1:4
      x-y
      [1] 0 0 0 0
```